# Automated way to check if layers are exactly the same using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm doing a voluntary project where I'm helping a client with an objection to a new road construction. The client, without much GIS knowhow, has provided me with a load of .dbf, .prj, .sbn, .sbx, .shp, .gfs and .shx-files he dragged from the municipality website about the project.

From a first visual inspection, the files seem to contain the same data, but I want to be sure before tossing them out; is there any way to have QGIScheck if the layers are the same?

Comment: Could you specify how much files there is + what type of entites are they (points, polygons, etc). Depending on the data, they might be some visual way or with some spatial analysis you can check too. Some hints could be number of entities, file and date size with classic file duplicate software, for example (see winmerge)